# python - matplotlib - Avoid plot text collisions with grid lines, border and other text

Tags: python, matplotlib, collision, scatter-plot

I'm generating a scatter plot and I was wondering if it is possible to avoid any overlaps between the gridlines and the text on the plot.

[image: Example Plot]

For example, the first point has its text on the gridline which makes it hard to read.

My code is below:

```
for i, j in zip(path_loss_list,throughput_values):
    plt.annotate( "%s" %str(j), xy=(i,j), xytext=(-5, 5), ha='right', textcoords='offset points')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you put all of the text directly above the plotted point, that you shouldn't have an issue.  Try, for example:

```
    for i, j in zip(path_loss_list,throughput_values):
        plt.annotate( "%s" %str(j), xy=(i,j), xytext=(0, 5), ha='right', textcoords='offset points')
```

However, this might cause some overlap with the point all the way on the right, in which case you can change `xytext = (0, 8).`  There might not be a consistent solution for all of your points.  Therefore, you might have to specify the text height on a point-by-point basis, such as:

```
   for i, j in zip(path_loss_list,throughput_values):
       if not j> 59:
           plt.annotate( "%s" %str(j), xy=(i,j), xytext=(-5, 5), ha='right', textcoords='offset points')
       else:
          plt.annotate( "%s" %str(j), xy=(i,j), xytext=(0, 5), ha='right', textcoords='offset points')
```

This will move the text for the top-most point.  You can extrapolate for y = 54.615.

Comment: first block works for me. I guess I have to keep playing with it depending on how many points I generate

Answer (score 2):

If i got this correctly, you want the grid line to be under your notes and points.
For this, use `ax.set_axisbelow(True)`, where ax is the axis that contains the gridlines.

http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=set_axisbelow#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axisbelow

You can also set it as a parameter of your script, so you don't have to change it everytime you trace it. Also, quite simple, just `matplotlib.rc('axes', axisbelow=True)`

To see more about rcParams, check http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc

and for a list of params http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html?highlight=rcparams